# Database content shows utf-8 encoded caracters but the ones written in php are not shown

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, smartphone

I have php website, my database content is encoded properly, but content i typed in html doesn't show utf-8 encoding caracters, when I am accessing site through my smartphone. 
I did put

```
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in my head tag, but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: For the purpose of error checking put the offending string within `utf8_encode($string)` and see if this resolves it.

Comment: where exactly to put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to execute this queries before selection of data:

```
SET NAMES UTF8; 
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

It will set the fetched data encoding to UTF-8.

Also, did you store your data or your script source code with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? Try to remove it using some text editor, i.e. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)